# Is Spring HATEOAS production ready?

Tags: spring, spring-hateoas

I'm in doubt whether Spring HATEOAS (latest v0.17.0) can be used in production or not.

I've seen that it's used in Spring Data REST 2.3.0 (**major version > 0**).

But, Spring HATEOAS major version is still **zero**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes spring-hateoas doesn't have a major release yet, but it had many minor releases which are pretty stable.

We are using spring-hateoas at a major telco company and we are in production successfully for some time now.

I don't expect backwards-compatibility breaking changes so it should be safe to use it. Oliver Gierke (project lead) is [actively fixing defects](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/graphs/contributors) so I wouldn't worry.

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 issues with `spring-hateoas:0.17.0.RELEASE`

The first issue is that the `Resource` class inherits a `getId()` annotated with `@JsonIgnore` which conflicts with entities that also have an `id` attribute. With XML it works fine.

For example, the `id` here won't be desserialized and your POJO will have a null instead:

```
   {
      "id": "55a53c35d4c6e3efd60fc31f",
      "name": "Portal",
      "_links": {
        "self": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8100/games/55a53c35d4c6e3efd60fc31f"
        }
      }
    }
```

But this will work perfectly:

```
<Resource xmlns="">
    <id>55a53e2ad4c6e74c6c09607d</id>
    <name>Portal</name>
    <links>
        <links>
            <rel>self</rel>
            <href>http://localhost:8100/games/55a53e2ad4c6e74c6c09607d</href>
        </links>
    </links>
</Resource>
```

The second issue is that the `links` are not being desserialized from the JSON response only, probably for a different reason now (which I still couldn't figure out). With XML it works fine again.

So back to the original question, after finding these issues in only a few hours playing with it, I believe it's not production ready. But I hope it will be soon, it's an amazing project, very intuitive and easy to use.